# Can I access app_data folder from ClassLibrary project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, class-library

I have a requirement that I have to upload a file in `App_Data` folder of asp.net MVC3. But before uploading this file I need to perform various operation on its content. These operations/functions are contained in `ClassLibrary` project.

So I want to know that Can I access `App_Data` folder from `ClassLibrary` project or not?

Comment: You can do any operation in ClassLibrary, using Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") you can add images there, but at finish, add ClassLibrary reference to ASP.NET application.